# Android How to slide row when previous row visibility set to Visible?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, tablerow

i am using table and using different control in rows as to perform like tree view functionality as i have not found any control to perform it.

i am doing programmatically so as to hide and view row on click text view my method is,

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tx;
            TableRow Row1, Row2;
            tx =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Row1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow3);
            Row2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow4);


        int rowOne = Row1.getVisibility();
        int rowTwo = Row2.getVisibility();
        if (rowOne == 0) {
            Row1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Row2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tx.setText("+ Building Replacement");
        } 
        else 
        {
            Row1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Row2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tx.setText("- Building Replacement");
        }
    }
```

on lick method to make table row visible.

But issue is table row is invisible initially on program load. Then there is empty space in it i wanna do some thing so that its row drag when previous row visibility set to visible.

How would can i do that ?

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

SOLUTION:

**View.Gone**  works for me !

Answer (score 0):

use `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in xml for allowing layout change animation

Link: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

Comment: thanks for your reply i have found solution mention in my post